# How to find, from where does a Yii method fetch data to query and how to update the query in the method to comply with GROUP BY?

Tags: php, sql, mysql, group-by, yii

I am new to Yii (not to PHP though)
I am trying to fix a Yii site that was created by someone else.
Data / contents are not shown after PHP and mySql update

I have this method in `/var/www/html/connect/models/UserDeviceLink.php`

```
public function findAllDevicesByUser($userId, $order = 'claimedAt')
    {
        $userId = !($userId) ? Yii::$app->user->id : $userId;
        $userIds = [];
        array_push($userIds, $userId);
        $myIds = User::instance()->getMyUsersIds($userId);
        #return $myIds; 
        
        if ($myIds) {
            foreach ($myIds as $key => $value) {
                array_push($userIds, $value);
            }
            array_unique($userIds);
        }

        if (!empty($devices = self::find()
            ->joinWith('device')
            ->orderBy($order . ' DESC')
            ->where(["userId" => $userIds])
            ->groupBy('deviceSerial')
            ->asArray()
            ->all())) {             
            return $devices;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

And we know if we have latest mySql and PHP, second '**if**' will not give any results as it is not comply with 'GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column' rules in latest mySql.

so this should be:

```
if (!empty($devices = self::find()
    ->joinWith('device')
    ->orderBy($order . ' DESC')
    ->where(["userId" => $userIds])
    ->groupBy('deviceSerial')
    ->asArray()
    ->all())) {             
    return $devices;
}
return null;
```

something like this (I changed and tried this):

```
if (!empty($devices = self::find()
    ->select([
        'deviceSerial',
    ])
    ->joinWith('device')
    ->orderBy($order . ' DESC')
    ->where(["userId" => $userIds])
    ->groupBy([
        'deviceSerial',
    ])
    ->asArray()
    ->all())) {             
    return $devices;
}

return null;
```

But this also does not return any results. I thought it will give at least single column results.

This is where the final results shown `/var/www/html/connect/views/platform/dashboard.php`

```
<table id="devicesTable" data-toggle="table" data-toolbar="#toolbar" data-cookie="true" data-cookie-id-table="devicesTable" data-search="true" data-search-align="right" data-show-search-button="true" data-search-on-enter-key="true" data-show-search-clear-button="true" data-sort-class="table-active" data-sortable="true" data-pagination="true" data-show-columns="false" data-show-fullscreen="true" data-show-toggle="true" data-buttons-align="left" data-virtual-scroll="true" data-mobile-responsive="true" data-check-on-init="true" data-url="<?= Url::toRoute(['platform/get-dashboard-json-table']) ?>">

  <thead class="g-letter-spacing-1">
    <tr>
      <th data-class="g-cursor-pointer" data-field="counter" data-sortable="true" class="g-font-weight-300 g-color-black">#</th>
      <th data-class="g-cursor-pointer" data-field="device" data-sortable="true" class="g-font-weight-300 g-color-black"><?= Yii::t('app', 'dashboard.table.device')?></th>
      <th data-class="g-cursor-pointer" data-field="location" data-sortable="true" class="g-font-weight-300 g-color-black g-min-width-200"><?= Yii::t('app', 'dashboard.table.location') ?></th>
      <th data-class="g-cursor-pointer" data-field="lastCycle" data-sortable="true" class="g-font-weight-300 g-color-black"><?= Yii::t('app', 'dashboard.table.last_cycle') ?></th>
      <th data-class="g-cursor-pointer" data-field="contacts" data-sortable="true" class="g-font-weight-300 g-color-black"><?= Yii::t('app', 'dashboard.table.contacts') ?></th>
      <th data-class="g-cursor-pointer" data-field="completetCycles" data-sortable="false" class="g-font-weight-300 g-color-black g-nowrap"><?= Yii::t('app', 'dashboard.table.completed_cycles') ?></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

and I found out that comes from here `/var/www/html/connect/models/TableData.php`

```
class TableData extends Model
{
    public function dashboard($data)
    {
        $tableData = [];

        $countData = isset($data) ? count($data) : 0;

        $tableData["total"] = $countData;

        $tableData["totalNotFiltered"] = $countData;

        $key = 0;

        if ($countData == 0) {
            return true;
        }

        foreach ($data as $tableRow) {
            $alias =
                $tableRow["device"]["alias"] !== null
                    ? "<strong>" .
                        $tableRow["device"]["alias"] .
                        "</strong><br>"
                    : "";

            if (
                $deviceSettings = DeviceSettings::find()
                    ->where(["serial" => $tableRow["device"]["serial"]])
                    ->one()
            ) {
                $targetCycles = (int) $deviceSettings->targetCycles;
            } else {
                $targetCycles = isset($tableRow["device"]["cycles"])
                    ? (int) $tableRow["device"]["cycles"]
                    : null;
            }

            $phoneNumber =
                isset($tableRow["device"]["apid_telefon"]) &&
                $tableRow["device"]["apid_telefon"] !== null &&
                $tableRow["device"]["apid_telefon"] !== ""
                    ? "<span class=\"d-block g-mb-5\"> <i class=\"fa fa-phone\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></i> <a href=\"tel:" .
                        htmlentities(
                            $tableRow["device"]["apid_telefon"],
                            ENT_QUOTES
                        ) .
                        "\">" .
                        htmlentities(
                            $tableRow["device"]["apid_telefon"],
                            ENT_QUOTES
                        ) .
                        "</a></span>"
                    : "";

            $contactEmail =
                isset($tableRow["device"]["apid_email"]) &&
                $tableRow["device"]["apid_email"] !== null &&
                $tableRow["device"]["apid_email"] !== ""
                    ? "<span class=\"d-block g-mb-5\"> <i class=\"fa fa-envelope\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></i> <a href=\"mailto:" .
                        htmlentities(
                            $tableRow["device"]["apid_email"],
                            ENT_QUOTES
                        ) .
                        "\">" .
                        htmlentities(
                            $tableRow["device"]["apid_email"],
                            ENT_QUOTES
                        ) .
                        "</a></span>"
                    : "";

            $company =
                "<strong>" . $tableRow["device"]["apid_firma"] . "</strong>";

            if (
                isset($tableRow["device"]["apid_firmab"]) &&
                $tableRow["device"]["apid_firmab"] !== null &&
                $tableRow["device"]["apid_firmab"] !== ""
            ) {
                $company =
                    "<strong>" .
                    htmlentities(
                        $tableRow["device"]["apid_firma"],
                        ENT_QUOTES
                    ) .
                    "</strong><br>" .
                    htmlentities(
                        $tableRow["device"]["apid_firmab"],
                        ENT_QUOTES
                    );
            }

            $isIndustrial =
                $tableRow["device"]["optionset"]["INDUSTRIALMODE"] == 1
                    ? "<span class=\"nottooltipped g-font-size-10\" data-toggle=\"tooltip\" data-placement=\"top\" data-original-title=\"" .
                        Yii::t("app", "device.vito_coolant") .
                        "\"> <i class=\"fa fa-industry\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></i></span> "
                    : "";

            $tableRowOffline =
                $tableRow["device"]["diff"] > 3
                    ? "<span class=\"fa-stack nottooltipped g-font-size-14\" data-toggle=\"tooltip\" data-placement=\"top\" data-html=\"true\" data-original-title=\"" .
                        Yii::t("app", "device.offline", [
                            "days" => htmlentities(
                                $tableRow["device"]["diff"],
                                ENT_QUOTES
                            ),
                        ]) .
                        " \"> <i class=\"fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x g-color-yellow\"></i> <i class=\"fa fa-exclamation-triangle fa-stack-1x g-color-black \"></i> </span>"
                    : "";

            $updateAvailable =
                $tableRow["device"]["updateAvailable"] !== false
                    ? "<span class=\"fa-stack nottooltipped g-font-size-14\" data-toggle=\"tooltip\" data-placement=\"top\" data-html=\"true\" data-original-title=\"" .
                        Yii::t("app", "device.new_version", [
                            "version" => htmlentities(
                                $tableRow["device"]["updateAvailable"],
                                ENT_QUOTES
                            ),
                        ]) .
                        " \"> <i class=\"fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x g-color-teal\"></i> <i class=\"fa fa-refresh fa-stack-1x g-color-white \"></i> </span>"
                    : "";

            $possibleCalc =
                $tableRow["device"]["possibleCalulation"] != true &&
                $tableRow["device"]["optionset"]["INDUSTRIALMODE"] === 0
                    ? "<span class=\"fa-stack nottooltipped g-font-size-14\" data-toggle=\"tooltip\" data-placement=\"top\" data-html=\"true\" data-original-title=\"" .
                        Yii::t("app", "device.calculation_not_possible_1") .
                        " " .
                        Yii::t("app", "device.calculation_not_possible_2") .
                        " <br>" .
                        Yii::t("app", "device.calculation_not_possible_3") .
                        " \"> <i class=\"fa fa-money fa-stack-1x g-color-black\"></i> <i class=\"fa fa-ban fa-stack-2x g-opacity-0_8 g-color-red\"></i> </span>"
                    : "";

            $allGood =
                $tableRow["device"]["updateAvailable"] == false &&
                $tableRow["device"]["diff"] <= 3 &&
                ($tableRow["device"]["possibleCalulation"] == true &&
                    $tableRow["device"]["optionset"]["INDUSTRIALMODE"] === 0)
                    ? "<span class=\"nottooltipped\" data-toggle=\"tooltip\" data-placement=\"top\" data-html=\"true\" data-original-title=\"<strong class='g-color-green'>" .
                        Yii::t("app", "device.all_ok") .
                        "</strong><br> " .
                        Yii::t("app", "device.all_ok.note") .
                        "\"><i class=\"fa fa-check g-color-green\"></i></span>"
                    : "";

            $labelCycles = "warning";

            $labelTodayCycles = "warning";

            $dayNumber = date("N");

            $cyclesToToday = round(($targetCycles / 7) * $dayNumber, 0);

            if ($targetCycles == 0) {
                $cyclesPercent = "∞";

                $cyclesToTodayPercent = "∞";
            } else {
                $cyclesPercent = round(
                    ($tableRow["device"]["weekCycles"] * 100) / $targetCycles,
                    0
                );

                if ($cyclesToToday == 0) {
                    $cyclesToTodayPercent = 0;
                } else {
                    $cyclesToTodayPercent = round(
                        ($tableRow["device"]["weekCycles"] * 100) /
                            $cyclesToToday,
                        0
                    );
                }
            }

            if (
                $targetCycles !== 0 &&
                $cyclesPercent <= Yii::$app->params["criticalDeltaPercent"]
            ) {
                $labelCycles = "danger";
            }

            if (
                $targetCycles !== 0 &&
                $cyclesPercent >=
                    100 - Yii::$app->params["criticalDeltaPercent"]
            ) {
                $labelCycles = "success";
            }

            if (
                $targetCycles !== 0 &&
                $cyclesPercent - Yii::$app->params["criticalDeltaPercent"] >=
                    100
            ) {
                $labelCycles = "danger";
            }

            if ($cyclesPercent == "∞") {
                $labelCycles = "danger";
            }

            if (
                $targetCycles !== 0 &&
                $cyclesToTodayPercent <=
                    Yii::$app->params["criticalDeltaPercent"]
            ) {
                $labelTodayCycles = "danger";
            }

            if (
                $targetCycles !== 0 &&
                $cyclesToTodayPercent >=
                    100 - Yii::$app->params["criticalDeltaPercent"]
            ) {
                $labelTodayCycles = "success";
            }

            if (
                $targetCycles !== 0 &&
                $cyclesToTodayPercent -
                    Yii::$app->params["criticalDeltaPercent"] >=
                    100
            ) {
                $labelTodayCycles = "danger";
            }

            if ($cyclesToTodayPercent == "∞") {
                $labelTodayCycles = "danger";
            }

            $tableData["rows"][$key]["counter"] = $key + 1;

            $tableData["rows"][$key][
                "device"
            ] = Helpers::instance()->simpleClean(
                "<div class=\"media\"> <div class=\"media-body align-self-center\"> <h5 class=\"h6 align-self-center g-font-weight-600 g-color-blue mb-0\">

                        " .
                    $tableRow["device"]["deviceName"]["name"] .
                    " " .
                    $isIndustrial .
                    $tableRowOffline .
                    $updateAvailable .
                    $possibleCalc .
                    $allGood .
                    "</h5>

                    <span class=\"g-font-size-12\">S/N: " .
                    $tableRow["device"]["serial"] .
                    "</span><br>

                    <span class=\"g-font-size-12\">Software: " .
                    $tableRow["device"]["version"] .
                    "</span>

                    </div>

                </div>"
            );

            $tableData["rows"][$key][
                "location"
            ] = Helpers::instance()->simpleClean(
                $alias .
                    "$company<br>" .
                    htmlentities($tableRow["device"]["apid_plz"], ENT_QUOTES) .
                    ", " .
                    htmlentities($tableRow["device"]["apid_ort"], ENT_QUOTES) .
                    ", " .
                    htmlentities($tableRow["device"]["apid_land"], ENT_QUOTES)
            );

            $tableData["rows"][$key]["lastCycle"] =
                $tableRow["device"]["timestamp"];

            $tableData["rows"][$key]["contacts"] = $phoneNumber . $contactEmail;

            $tableData["rows"][$key][
                "completetCycles"
            ] = Helpers::instance()->simpleClean(
                "<span class=\"u-label u-label-" .
                    $labelTodayCycles .
                    " g-color-white g-px-10\">" .
                    $tableRow["device"]["weekCycles"] .
                    "/" .
                    $cyclesToToday .
                    "</span> due until today (" .
                    $cyclesToTodayPercent .
                    "%)<br><span class=\"u-label u-label-" .
                    $labelCycles .
                    " g-color-white g-px-10\">" .
                    $tableRow["device"]["weekCycles"] .
                    "/" .
                    $targetCycles .
                    "</span> due this week (" .
                    $cyclesPercent .
                    "%)"
            );

            $tableData["rows"][$key]["link"] =
                Url::toRoute(["platform/device"]) .
                "/" .
                $tableRow["device"]["serial"];

            $key++;
        }

        return $tableData;
    }
}
```

Full file is here TableData.php (if you want to have a look): https://onlinephp.io/c/505e1

**Question:**

how to update the fetching part in the method '`findAllDevicesByUser`' as per this data to comply with the latest mySql `GROUP BY` clause and show the final results like this ? [SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7Bmw.png)